# 2D Canvas (behind a 3D Canvas) not drawing images

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I'm currently exploring with Three.js, and working on a small project of mine.
The project consists on having a canvas focused on 3D models and animations, and another one behind, which handles the simpler 2D work.

I've set up the 3D canvas properly, so it's background is transparent, and I can see boxes I draw manually on the 2D canvas, which leads me to assume the setup is right.

The issue I'm having is when it comes to images. I simply cannot get an image to display on the 2D canvas. I've experimented on a separate project, and could draw Images there, no problem. The code is pretty basic, and I actually found it here, but is as follows:

```js
window.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('bgcanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var logoText = new Image();

      logoText.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(logoText, 69, 50);
      };
      logoText.src = 'images/logotext.png';
}
```

```css
#canvas {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 0;
}
#bgcanvas {
 z-index: -10;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixedContainer">
  <canvas id="bgcanvas"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

What's going on that I'm unaware of?
Massive thanks in advance!

UPDATE EDIT: The issue was that I had an image on which the top left corner was transparent, and didn't know the image would stretch. user3412847's comment helped me figure it out

Comment: Just an fyi: In case you didn't know and started to wonder why your images look strange (stretched) it's becuase you've set the width and height of the canvas in your CSS. The standard size of a canvas is 300x150 pixels and using CSS to change the size will stretch it. Instead use `canvas.width=100;` and `canvas.height=100` to alter the canvas' size.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thanks for the tip! I'll change my code once the image issue goes away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying image `width` and `height` is a good habit to get into. Use this syntax: `context.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, turns out part of the solution was ... Being less silly. The image had it's upper left corner transparent, but I had no clue the image would be stretched to the full width of the canvas if I used CSS to resize it. Directly giving the image a width and height made me understand my mistake. I'm really grateful for your help and tips!

Comment: No, you always have to declare the onload-function before assigning the .src, otherwise, the image will start to load before you've told it what it should do when it's done loading.

Comment: @Niddro thanks for the tip off, didn't know this was the case.

Comment: @Niddro Turns out your comment was part of the answer aswell, so, thanks once more.

Comment: No problem, @user3412847 make sure to edit your answer, removing that last advice so that other users that come here looking for answers gets it wrong =)

Comment: I updated the question aswell, to help people get directly to the problem, as I feel the question could be misleading since not all images' corners are transparent

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't have an image at that path; It works fine for me with a valid image (eg: http://lorempixel.com/100/100):

```js
window.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('bgcanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var logoText = new Image();

      logoText.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(logoText, 69, 50);
      };
      logoText.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100';
}
```

```css
#canvas {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 0;
}
#bgcanvas {
 z-index: -10;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixedContainer">
  <canvas id="bgcanvas"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I do have an image there, I made sure I checked it a couple of times before asking. As I said, it works perfectly fine in a different file, which is what these snippets emulate, but when put together with the other foreground canvas, the image won't display.

Thanks a lot, though!

Comment: Have you tried specifying width and height (`context.drawImage(image, x, y, w, h)`)? Just a thought.

Comment: If above code doesn't help, I think it's time to have a look at the rest of your code, something there is probably messing things up.